# Unable to migrate my blogger to WordPress

Tags: blogger

I recently started a WordPress.org blog with hosting for my blog [WorkerVoice.in](https://www.workervoice.in/)and am looking to import my blog from Blogger. This seems very straight forward and when I previously used WordPress.com, it worked no problem. I have already set up my two website also these methods. A few clicks and it was up and running with all my blog posts, photos and comments from Blogger.
For the record, this is what I’ve been met with when trying to import my Blogger blog …
1.  Tools > import > Blogger Run Importer > Choose File > Upload file and import
2.  It loads at the bottom of my screen by % then once it’s complete all it displays is a button that says “Submit”. No other text.
3.  Then all it says is “All done. Have fun! Remember to update the passwords and roles of imported users.” and nothing has changed. I can’t find my blog posts anywhere.
I also try https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer-extended/ but every time got error message “Oops! Something went wrong. Click the button below to reload the connection to Blogger. The importer will continue afterwards.”
If anyone has any help I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!
Surjeet Shyamal